# Fade draw and fill in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

In TikZ one can fade objects using the fadings library.
I want to fill and draw a circle and fade the whole object.
However, the fade option only affects the filling.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[color = black, fill = blue, path fading = west] (0, 0) circle (1.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Resulting TikZ image]

Is there a way to fade the circle and the filling?

Answer (score 7):

like this?

[image]

you shouldn't explicit declare draw color:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[very thick, fill = blue, path fading = west] (0, 0) circle (1.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, like this! Unfortunately, if I compile your code I get the same output as before, i.e., no faded circle. Did you compile it using pdflatex?

Comment: @snem, i compile width `pdflatex` (recent version of `miktex` and `tikz`).  it also work with `xelatex`.

Answer (score 3):

An idea is to use just fill command and create a bigger filled black circle bellow the next (blue). The blue will be placed over the black and the only visible part will become a surrounding on second circle:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[black, path fading= west] (0, 0) circle (1.01);
  \fill[ fill = blue, path fading = west] (0, 0) circle (1.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Improving the idea:

We can create a command that will reduce the inner circle size (radius) by 
(line width)/2 from the given radius and extend the outer circle radius by the same length. Then the the "visible line" (surrounding) of the circle will have the usual width and the result will be like Zarkos (better) solution.

PS: Just leaving the answer as an idea for similar problems... But Zarco's answer is the real answer (Mine can shade surrounding from right to left or top to bottom or rotated etc)

Comment: Interesting idea, maybe I'll come back to it, if other ways don't work.